# Qt Quick Controls 2.14 how to style ScrollView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

It is not clear how to style the QML ScrollView.
I want to have the below style for the ScrollView but getting error `style` as invalid property.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

ScrollView {
    style: ScrollViewStyle {
        handle: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "red"
        }
        scrollBarBackground: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "black"
        }
        decrementControl: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "green"
        }
        incrementControl: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

**Update:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

ScrollView {
    id: myScrollView
    width: 700
    height: parent.height
    clip: true

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        id: scrollBar
        parent: myScrollView.parent
        policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        anchors.top: myScrollView.top
        anchors.left: myScrollView.right
        anchors.bottom: myScrollView.bottom
        height: myScrollView.availableHeight

        contentItem: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 16
            implicitHeight: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 10

            radius: 16
            color: "blue"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: myListView
        anchors.fill: parent

    .... Rest of the code ....
```

With above code I could get the style for the vertical scrall bar but with this code I see two scrolls bars. One with light gray color with very small size and one with blue color as per the above style.

Also the height of the blue scroll bar is not as per the style.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for the second "small light gray" scroll bar that appears in addition to the styled one?

I'm using `QtQuick 2.15` and `QtQuick.Controls 2.15` and have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing Qt Quick Controls 1 with Qt Quick Controls 2. QQC2 does not use a `style` property. Here are the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-scrollview). The basic idea for a ScrollView is that you can change the `background` and also the `ScrollBar` that gets attached.

```
ScrollView {
    background: ... // This changes what's drawn in the background

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { ... }
    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { ... }
}
```

And a `ScrollBar` itself can be customized as well by changing the `background` or `contentItem`.

```
ScrollBar {
    background: ... // Change the background of the scrollbar
    contentItem: ... // Change the scroll indicator
}
```

**UPDATE:** Actually, I see the same behavior you do when I try it. I was just following the docs, so maybe there's a Qt bug there. The good news is since you're just trying to scroll a `ListView`, the `ScrollView` is actually unnecessary. You can just do this:

```
    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: 200
        height: 200
        model: 100
        clip: true
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            text: modelData
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            background: Rectangle { color: "red" }
            contentItem: Rectangle { implicitWidth: 10; implicitHeight: 10; color: "blue" }
        }
    }
```

I tried it myself this time and it worked.

Comment: for the line `ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { ... }` getting error `Cannot assign a value directly to a grouped property`

Comment: Make sure to remove this line: `import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4`. That's from QQC1.

Comment: thanks, but for testing when I add the `contentItem:` and set the color to red (for testing), I don't see red color is getting set, even my scroll indicator becomes very small and my list does not scroll.

Comment: Added code snippet. I could get the style set to the scroll bar but now I see two vertical scroll bars. One with my style and one I think default.