# Styling QtQuick2 ScrollView results in visible artifacts

Tags: qml, scrollview, scrollbar, styling

I have asked this question already directly on the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/143119/styling-qtquick2-scrollview-results-in-visible-artifacts), but no reactions till now, hopefully I have more luck here.

We are currently updating from Qt5.12.12 to Qt5.15.8 and have to update our `ScrollView` component to match our design.

The problem is, that we now see artifacts that look like an `ScrollBar` without styling when hovering the `ScrollBar`. You can see an artifact in the left corner of the horizontal `ScrollBar` when hovering over the vertical one and vice versa. When timed correctly both artifacts are visible at the same time.

The problem only occurs when the styled `ScrollView` itself is used as an `component`. Either in an extra file or as `inline component`.
I attached a minimal broken example in the code below. The left most `ScrollView` shows the artifacts.

I'm thankful to everyone who can confirm this problem and even more if you have an suggestion on how to fix it.
Thank you.

Example:

[image: Example output with artifacts]

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQml 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
  id: window
  width: 750
  height: 300
  
  readonly property int scrollBarWidth: 15
  
  //////////////////////////////
  
  component MyStyledScrollBar: ScrollBar {
    id: myScrollBarRoot
    //parent: myScrollViewRoot

    opacity: 0.4

    x: myScrollBarRoot.horizontal
      ? parent.leftPadding
      : parent.width - width
    y: myScrollBarRoot.horizontal
      ? parent.height - height
      : parent.topPadding

    width: myScrollBarRoot.horizontal
     ? parent.availableWidth
     : window.scrollBarWidth
    height: myScrollBarRoot.horizontal
     ? window.scrollBarWidth
     : parent.availableHeight

    contentItem: Rectangle {
      color: "green"
    } //Rectangle
  } //component StyledScrollBar: ScrollBar

  component MyScrollView: ScrollView {
    id: myScrollViewRoot

    clip: true

    rightPadding: window.scrollBarWidth
    rightInset: window.scrollBarWidth
    bottomPadding: window.scrollBarWidth
    bottomInset: window.scrollBarWidth

    ScrollBar.vertical: MyStyledScrollBar {
      parent: myScrollViewRoot
      policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
      active: myScrollViewRoot.ScrollBar.horizontal.active
    } //ScrollBar.vertical: MyStyledScrollBar

    ScrollBar.horizontal: MyStyledScrollBar {
      parent: myScrollViewRoot
      policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
      active: myScrollViewRoot.ScrollBar.vertical.active
    } //ScrollBar.vertical: MyStyledScrollBar
  } //component MyScrollView: ScrollView
  
  //////////////////////////////
  
  GridLayout {
    flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
    rows: 2
    columnSpacing: 15
    rowSpacing: 5

    //////////////////////////////

    Text {
      text: "Inline Component"
    } //Text
  
    MyScrollView {
      Layout.preferredWidth: 200
      Layout.preferredHeight: 200
  
      Label {
        text: "ABC"
        font.pixelSize: 224
      } //Label
    } //MyScrollView
  
    //////////////////////////////
  
    Text {
      text: "Direct Styling"
    } //Text
  
    ScrollView {
      id: scrollViewRoot
      Layout.preferredWidth: 200
      Layout.preferredHeight: 200

      Label {
        text: "ABC"
        font.pixelSize: 224
      } //Label

      clip: true

      rightPadding: window.scrollBarWidth
      rightInset: window.scrollBarWidth
      bottomPadding: window.scrollBarWidth
      bottomInset: window.scrollBarWidth

      ScrollBar.vertical: MyStyledScrollBar {
        policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        active: scrollViewRoot.ScrollBar.horizontal.active
      } //ScrollBar.vertical: MyStyledScrollBar

      ScrollBar.horizontal: MyStyledScrollBar {
        policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        active: scrollViewRoot.ScrollBar.vertical.active
      } //ScrollBar.vertical: MyStyledScrollBar
    } //ScrollView
  
    //////////////////////////////
  
    Text {
      text: "ScrollView default"
    } //Text
  
    ScrollView {
      ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
      ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
  
      clip: true
  
      Layout.preferredWidth: 200
      Layout.preferredHeight: 200
  
      Label {
        text: "ABC"
        font.pixelSize: 224
      } //Label
    } //MyScrollView
  } //GridLayout
} //Window
```

ps: In Qt6 the `ScrollView` looks a lot different to Qt5.15 more like it was in QtQuick1, with increase/decrease buttons which we need to add manually with Qt5.15 ... . But we can not yet make the jump Qt6

Comment: I have found a hint that I'm not alone withe this problem already days ago but could not follow up on fixing it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906680/qt-quick-controls-2-14-how-to-style-scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QtQuick [templates](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-templates2-qmlmodule.html) namely `T.ScrollView`. This will ensure there is no visual part left from the QtQuick.Controls implementation of `ScrollView`.

```
import QtQuick.Templates 2.15 as T
...
component MyScrollView: T.ScrollView {
    ...
}
```

Comment: For more info, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-96733. In Qt 6.5 the user will get a warning when customising native styles.

Comment: Thank you a lot that fixed the problem quick and easy.
Until now QtQuick.Templates avoided my research.